# How change object attributes in game

Tags: python, game-engine, objects

I have two scenes ["scene", "HUD"].
In "HUD" is a healthBar (plane), in "scene" is a player, that contains collision sensor and python controller. I need to reduce player's health and show it in HUD. This is my script:

```
import bpy
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
health = cont.owner["Health"] #Health is property
health -= 10

#try change healthBar dimension - full health has dimensions[1] = 1.0
hb = bpy.data.objects["HealthBar"]

hb.dimensions[1] = health/100

cont.owner["Health"] = health
```

This is not working. Dimensions of "HealthBar" changes, but only after the game (When I run game again, I see healthBar smaller). Where is the problem? Is there any function to update view, refresh or redraw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these two lines, because the bpy module does not wok in the game engine.

`hb = bpy.data.objects["HealthBar"]`
should be changed to the code block below.

```
hud = None

for scene in bge.logic.getSceneList():
    if scene.name == "HUD":
        hud = scene
        break
hb = hud.objects["HealthBar"]
```

That loops through all the scenes in the game, and assigning a var of `hud` to the scene named HUD. Then the last line gets the object named HealthBar in the HUD scene.

Or simply this line if the object was in the same scene.
`hb = bge.logic.getCurrentScene().objects["HealthBar"]`

---

Your `hb.dimensions[1] = health/100` line
must be changed to `hb.worldScale[1] = health/100` (because there is no dimensions attribute in the game engine).